# Create rectangular shapes-like frames as think-cell does

Tags: microsoft-excel, shapes

I want to learn the way [think-cell](https://www.think-cell.com/) creates its denotation of the linked range in Excel sheet, like the light blue framing in the picture below (or at the end of [this clip](https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxwVMaYQ_dqE7nkvlogewIDChn020WVpSf)).

It's a rectangular shape that "recognizes" the bounds of the range and adheres to them. You can shrink / expand this shape manually by pulling the framing with a mouse, and when you do it feels like "sticky" to the cells' boundaries. So the question is how can I create that kind of a rectangular framing in Excel on a standalone basis, regardless of think-cell add-in?

[image: The way this shape looks like in Excel]

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Is there a reason adding a stroke around the given area does not work for you?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, cells' stroke resides in the same level as all the other cells' formatting. You can't pull the stroke manually without breaking the formatting of the adjacent cells. While this think-cell's rectangular denotation lives in the level "above" the cells, similar to the way shapes do. In a manner it's a type of a shape, but unlike other shapes, it "recognizes" the cells' boundaries and sticks to them. This is something you can't achieve with cells' stroke.